# Expendable ListView parent child Communication

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In `ExpendableListView`, i create a child with `edittext` . and a `TextView` in the parent 
i want when the user enter some value in the `editText` in the `childView` the value is also set for the `textView` in parent

Answer (score 0):

`ExpendableListView` is not better, you can see the  [google deskclock source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/)

Comment: zys  i did not get you